# How get in CSS a link underlined

Tags: css

I want in one specific class my links underlined. But somehow I can't figure out why it's not working

this is my code

```
.kleiner {
    a:link text-decoration: underline;
    font-size: 75%;

}
```

Comment: Please learn the basis of CSS before asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your css should be    `.kleiner a:link {text-decoration: underline; font-size: 75%;}`

Answer (score 0):

Your [Css structure](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_syntax.asp) is completely wrong.

```
.kleiner a:link {
    text-decoration: underline;
    font-size: 75%;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.kleiner a:link{
    text-decoration: underline;
    font-size: 75%;
}
```

Comment: But then the whole class is underlined. I want online the link underlined

Answer (score 0):

That's not correct CSS code. It can't work. In pure CCS your code should look like this (I assume you want your links to be decorated with an underline and smaller)

```css
.kleiner a:link {
   color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="kleiner">
  <p>Some text</p>
  <a href="#">Some link</a>
</div>
```

This is really basic stuff. A needed info you can easily find in any CSS tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

For the `<a>` tag the `text-decoration: underline;` property is default property, It may not work unless you have override globally.

Please try to with using `text-decoration: underline !important`.

This may help.

Thanks :).